# How to add menu item to add a new file type from Add new file window in visual studio

Tags: .net, vspackage

We need to add a new file option in File Menu -> New File(Ctrl + N) in Visual Studio using Visual Studio Package.

We could add the menu in the context menu of visual studio through .vsct file adding some tags. But we couldn't find out how to insert the same option in the window which appears while we click on File->New File in the main menu in visual studio.

Can somebody please help to find out how to include a new file in the window that appears when we click the new file option

In the below image a dialog box is shown. We want to add a new type of file like Text file or Javascript file(in the image) in that window

[image]

Comment: You didn't even Google this.

Comment: Hi, we tried searching in google the problem is i couldn't find out how to customize the new file options in visual studio. It would be great if some one can suggest some ideas or information related to this

Comment: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165739.aspx) [2](http://blog.slaks.net/2014-08-26/adding-menu-items-to-a-visual-studio-extension/) [3](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2014/02/18/who-said-building-visual-studio-extensions-was-hard) Each one of these explains what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question is that something in the title and in the explanation mentions "adding a menu item", or "file options" which is not the proper way of expressing it. What you want is to add a "project item template" (or "item template") in the "New File" dialog of Visual Studio.

The docs:

Creating Visual Studio Templates
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx

How to: Create Item Templates
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx

More info: search the "Templates" subsections on each top section (Documentation, Articles, Videos, Samples, etc.) of my web site:
http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/